# Random extra padding added onto elements?

Tags: html, css

SOLVED: Look at the comments for possible solution.

I'm in the process of creating my own website, and I made an about me section with a header and paragraph and then decided to make it like a box. For some reason I get this huge amount of extra padding (even if I completely take out the padding in the css) at the top or the sides. 
An image of what's happening if I set width to 200px : https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3oXX.png
If I set width to 400px: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgn27.png

```css
#about
{
 color: whitesmoke;
 background: black;
 position: relative;
 right: -500px;
 width: 400px;
}

#about h3
{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: whitesmoke;
}

#about p
{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
    <h3>About Me</h3>
    <p>
        Text text text text text text text text text text text text text           text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text    text text text text text text
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no image in there that is not loading ? Looks like an element around which the text wraps. (*maybe a `:before` pseudo-element*). We will have to see it in action to provide more help..

Comment: Well there we go. That was it. I remembered the clear property and added that in there and it's all fixed now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edit your first post if you have resolved your problem